# How to design the signature of this method

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I need to define a method, which takes a request and returns a response:

```
  public MyResponse submit(MyRequest request){                      A
      ....
  }
```

This looks simple. However:

MyRequest can has a number of child classes

```
 public class HolidayRequest extends MyRequest {}
 public class FundingRequest extends MyRequest {}
 public class BudgetRequest extends MyRequest {}
```

The same applies to the response class:

```
 public class HolidayResponse extends MyResponse {}
 public class FundingResponse extends MyResponse {}
 public class BudgetResponse extends MyResponse {}
```

A user of the method `submit` can pass in a request of any type and get a corresponding response object, e.g.: Pass in HolidayRequest will return HolidayResponse.

Although the interface defined above still works, the user has to cast the return value of `submit` from MyResponse to a specific response type.

I then think to change the method to:

```
  public <T extends MyResponse, S extends MyRequest>                B
  T submit(S request){
      ....
  }
```

This allows the return type to be a specific type rather than the parent type. However, a user can still write code like:

```
  HolidayResponse response = submit(new FundingRequest());
```

and the code will still compile but fail at runtime.

Then I realise the submit method does not need to know which type of request it is, so there is no need to use type parameter for MyRequest, I think I can maybe further simplify it to:

```
  public <T extends MyResponse>                                    C
  T submit(MyRequest request){
      ....
  }
```

But again, this one has the same problem as mentioned above, user can pass in a request type and expect another response type.

My question is that how I shall properly define the signature of this method? Which one of the A, B and C definition above will you use? Or there might be more appropriate way to define it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You have to link your `Request` to your `Response`.

For example, change the `MyRequest` class to

```
public abstract class MyRequest<T extends MyResponse> {
```

Now your `HolidayRequest` would look like:

```
public class HolidayRequest extends MyRequest<HolidayResponse> {
```

Now your method signature can force the `MyReponse` to correspont:

```
public <R extends MyResponse, S extends MyRequest<R>> R submit(S request){

}
```